# Popup window in grails

Tags: grails, popup

I have a text area and a button. When a button is click a popup window should be display, with a list of text. How can i accomplish this? I tried to use Modalbox plugin and when an action is called its not getting the text area input.

I tried this. Are there other solution for popup or there's a work around in modalbox plugin?

```
<modalbox:createLink controller="MGExecutingGroup" action="addEG_Create" id="600001" title="Add Executing Group" width="800"><g:actionSubmit name="createAdd" action="addEG_Create" value=" + " /> </modalbox:createLink>
```

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Comment: @user2264997 there, i edited the post.

Comment: you can use twitter bootstrap modals http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
they are easy to use and good looking, let me know in case you will have any issue in it, in case you want to use them :)

Comment: @SaurabhDixit I used it and i was able to display the popup. Now how can I call the controller that gets the textbox input?

Comment: use a form on the popup to send text input to controller, 
<g:form action="<your action name>" controller="<controller name>">

</g:form>
by the time you will submit this form, you will be able to get the value in the text fields in the params in the controller's action.

even for AJAX you can use grails formRemote :)

Comment: the controller is not called when i use the g:form

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I found if you called the action from the modalbox, it should return the value of your text area. In that case from your link I dont see you haven't passed your textarea value to the action. If you want to use that modal box plugin work around how to pass the text are value to the action using modal box.

Otherwise
you can use use the twiiter bootstrap modal its easy to use.
you can see the more details in the following link
[Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html)

[Many modal demos using twitter bootstrap available available here](http://bootstrap2modaldemo.scripting.com/#)